# Use ui:include to only include part of a page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, uiinclude

I am creating a documentation page for my JSF web app and would like to include parts of the documentation as in a p:tooltip in the actual web page.  Is there a way to only include certain divs in a ui:include?  If this is the code of my documentation page:

```
<h:body>
    <div id="thisOne">
        <h:outputText value="should show"/>
    </div>
    <div id="notthis" >
        <h:outputText value="This shouldn't show"/>
    </div>             
</h:body>
```

How would I do a ui:include which only includes the div with the id: "thisOne"?

Answer (score 2):

> How would I do a ui:include which only includes the div with the id:
>   "thisOne"?

You would create a page wrapped in the templating tag `ui:composition`, then use the tag `ui:include` to include it in the main page.

Like this (with files in the same folder) :

**thisOne.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <div id="thisOne">
        <h:outputText value="should show"/>
    </div>
</ui:composition>
```

**main.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
   <h:head>
  </h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form >
        <ui:include src="thisOne.xhtml" />
     </h:form>
    <div id="notthis" >
        <h:outputText value="This shouldn't show"/>
    </div>             
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know I can make separate files and include them, but I would like to avoid this.  How can I make only one file and include certain divs in that file?

Comment: I guess you can convert the divs to jsf/primefaces components and use the rendered attribute. Or just surround them with components. For example <p:outputPanel style="display:block" rendered="...">. Otherwise you can't do what you want

Comment: @user2585366 I do not understand your requirement then. What do you mean by include certain divs in that file ? What's the purpose of `ui:include` here ? Please explain clearly.